# Java Spring Hibernate and Reflection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, reflection

I have 5 tables in MySQL (words_1, words_2... words_5)  with the same fields (id,words,sinonim). In the field "words" I put different count of words (for words_1 = 1 word, for
words_5 = 5 words). I create 5 classes and Repo for those.
Constructors and methods are the same.

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "words_2")
public class Words2 {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String word;
    private String sinonim;

    public Words2() {
    }

    public Words2(String word, String sinonim) {
        this.word = word;
        this.sinonim = sinonim;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public String getSinonim() {
        return sinonim;
    }

    public void setSinonim(String sinonim) {
        this.sinonim = sinonim;
    }
}
```

How I can take my classes fields and methods, using variable(int = 1..5) with Reflection, for Class and same Repo identification?

Comment: This is a strange table design. Why not keep all data in one table with an additional column telling what kind of "word" it is? Then you would need any reflection. Your question sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: because there are a few millions records in each table. I do it for optimization

Comment: I can do it with "Switch" in Controller . But i think it's a wrong way

Comment: Preoptimization is a root to a lot of evils. Have you measured it or do you just think it will be required?

Comment: The service works for me, it changes the texts. The algorithm is as follows: It takes the first 5 words in the text, searches for matches in the table, if it finds it, it takes the next words, if it doesn’t find it, it takes 4 words and brushes the match in the table, if it doesn’t find it, 3, etc.
One sentence for me produces 20 - 100 calls to the database. Already, the processing of one sentence takes 1-2 seconds. As the number of words in the tables increases, the time will increase.

Comment: I passed the model and int to a method that fetches the class and repository and returned the modified model. Everything works, thank you.